# AIC versus model diagnostics, which one to go by?

Tags: aic, diagnostic

I fitted model 1 and model 2. I then plotted the residual plots.

Model 1 had some minor problems with the residual plot: there was more variance in the residuals on the right side than on the left. This suggests that variance is not constant.

Model 2 was fitted where the variance could depend on a predictor $x$. The residual plot of this model looks very good.

However, AIC on model 1 and model 2 suggests that model 1 is better.

I too would like to continue with model 1, as it is more tractable.

So, what do I go with? AIC, or judge by the residual plot?

Comment: You are talking about tools that accomplish different things here. AIC and other measures of goodness of fit help you to select between different models, whilst model diagnostics are meant to let you know if your data violate any important assumption of the model you are trying to fit. A better goodness of fit in a model where an important assumption is violated shouldn't be taken as evidence that it is the preferred model: it is likely to have problems due to the assumptions not being met.

Comment: I don't quite understand that. Model 2 fits a variance structure simply by directly modelling the variance as a function of the predictor $x$, i.e. $\sigma \sim x$. Model 1 is identical, except it has $\sigma \sim 1$. So, we would have no problems using AIC to compare the models $\mu \sim x$ versus $\mu \sim 1$, so why is it not okay to use AIC to compare $\sigma \sim x$ versus $\sigma \sim 1$? The only difference is that the parameter being expressed as a function of covariates is variance $\sigma^2$, and not mean $\mu$ ..... ?

Comment: What I mean to say is, when I see AIC used in other papers, they usually don't do model diagnostics for every model used in the AIC comparisons. They fit, say, 10 models, and then they compare them ALL with AIC, and then just pick one and go with it. Only after do they perform model diagnostics on the chosen model, i.e., AIC comes before model diagnostics?

Comment: The sequence you describe is common. and the reason is not deep. People don't have the time for detailed tinkering with a large number of models. The cost exceeds the benefit.

Comment: What's the difference in AIC ($\Delta AIC$) between your 2 models?  Within 4 you can assume both models are the same and then choose the one you prefer

Comment: Essentially, the OP wants to know if it is ok to use a model that violates a key assumption. It depends on his goals with the analysis and which assumption it was, but the main problem here is that he is talking about two different things: a measure of fit and a way to verify assumptions. Even if he would go with what is done in practice and first compare fit for all models and then see if the chosen model meets all assumptions, in this case the favoured model by AIC has problems that need to be dealt with (by different error structures or robust SEs, for example).